# How to NOT use \n as delimiter in getline()

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in lines from a plain text file, but there are line breaks in the middle of sentences, so getline() reads until a line break as well as until a period. The text file looks like:

```
then he come tiptoeing down and stood right between us. we could
a touched him nearly. well likely it was minutes and minutes that
there warnt a sound and we all there so close together. there was a
place on my ankle that got to itching but i dasnt scratch it.
```

My read-in code:

```
  // read in sentences
  while (file)
  {
    string s, record;
    if (!getline( file, s )) break;
    istringstream ss(s);

    while (ss)
    {
      string s;

      if (!getline(ss, s, '.')) break;
          record = s;
      if(record[0] == ' ')
          record.erase(record.begin());

      sentences.push_back(record);
    }
  }

  // output sentences
  for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++)
    cout << sentences[i] << "[][][][]" << endl;
```

The purpose of the [ ][ ][ ][ ] was to check if linebreaks were used as delimiters and were not just being read into the string. The output would look like:

```
then he come tiptoeing down and stood right between us.[][][][]
we could[][][][]
a touched him nearly.[][][][]
well likely it was minutes and minutes that[][][][]
there warnt a sound and we all there so close together.[][][][]
there was a[][][][]
place on my ankle that got to itching but i dasnt scratch it.[][][][]
```

Comment: Are you sure that you get the `'.'` characters in your output from executing your example code?  That shouldn't be happening (and doesn't in my test of your code snippet).

Comment: Have you tried `std::ostringstream oss; oss << file.rdbuf();`?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question?

You're using `getline()` to read from the `file` stream with a newline delimiter, then parsing that line with a `getline()` using the `istringstream is` and a delimiter `'.'`.  So of course you're getting your strings broken at both the new line and the `'.'`.

Answer (score 0):

> getdelim() works like getline(), except that a line delimiter other than newline can be specified as the delimiter argument.  As with getline(), a delimiter character is not added if one was not present in the input before end of file was reached.

[ssize_t getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, int delimiter, FILE *restrict stream);](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: `getdelim` is not a function from the C++ standard library.

Comment: It's from exactly the same library as `getline`.  It's in `stdio.h`.  I guess it's not in `stdlib.h`, but I would still consider it part of the standard C library.

Comment: No it is not. The standard C library is what the C standard says is the standard C library, not what you can find in a header on your computer. The C standard does not define `getline`. POSIX defines `getline`, but the original question is about `std::getline` from the C++ standard library. `std::getline` is quite different from POSIX `getline`, it has a different interface and is available on a different set of platforms.